# Drupal is not bootstrapped

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

When I try to manually bootstrap Drupal from a standalone PHP script it just silently fails. I do the following:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

chdir('/var/www/dev_site');
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1';
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc'; 
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

die('drupal loaded');
```

The script fails on `drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);` The last die command never gets executed, the script just terminates wthout any error message.

**OS: CentOS 6.6, PHP: 5.5.27: Drupal: 7.34**

Can anyone advise please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! After digging into drupal_bootstrap function I found that it failed while executing init hooks. Soon I found that it failed on Restrict IP module hook. The reason is that 127.0.0.1 IP address was not whitelisted. Once I added it to the whitelist it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

Basic bootstrap I'm using (default one I guess) looks like this:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

So, try removing rows you added to figure out which one is causing the problem

Comment: drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL) is causing problems, but how can I debug it further?

Comment: Hmm...if it won't run well when you have only those 3 lines then I guess something is wrong with your system settings. This works for me well. Check apache error log. Or try it on some other environment...Wamp/ Mapm or something similar...

Comment: Yes, it's something with the system, but what exactly? This script works if I run it through a web server, but when I run it through PHP CLI it fails for a some reason.